# JTable cell is not updating with periodic update

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am using JTable for showing information about files selected from the JFileChooser. When i click upload button, my actual upload will start by picking up the selected files from the table, and it will try to update file upload status in JTable for corresponding files. Here when am trying to update the value in the status field of JTable when file upload is in progress, it's been updated for couple times only.It is starting with 0 and directly it is updating 100, but am not able to see other progress values. Please have a look into following code,

**My Table Code:**

```
uploadTableModel = new UploadTabModel();
uploadTable = new JTable(uploadTableModel);
uploadTable.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_NEXT_COLUMN);
uploadTable.setAutoCreateRowSorter(false);
uploadTable.setShowGrid(false);
uploadTable.setVisible(true);
JScrollPane tablePane = new JScrollPane();
tablePane.setViewportView(uploadTable);
```

**My Table Model:**

```
public class UploadTabModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    private List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
    private List<FileDTO> data = new ArrayList<FileDTO>();
    public CMUploadTabModel() {

        names.add("Name");
        names.add("Size");
        names.add("Status");
    }
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3151839788636790436L;

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return names.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
        FileDTO file = data.get(row);
        switch (col) {
        case 0:
            return file.getFileName();
        case 1:
            return file.getSize();
        case 2:
            return file.getStatus();
        }
        return file.getFileName();
    }

    @Override
    public void setValueAt(Object arg0, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        FileDTO file = data.get(rowIndex);
        switch (columnIndex) {
            case 2:
                file.setStatus((Integer) arg0);
                break;
        }
    }

    public void addRow(FileDTO file) {
        this.data.add(file);
        this.fireTableRowsInserted(data.size() - 1, data.size() - 1);
    }

    public String getColumnName(int columnIndex) {
        return names.get(columnIndex);
    }


    @Override
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int index) {
        return getValueAt(0, index).getClass();
    }
    public void updateProgress(int index, final int percentage) {

        FileDTO file = data.get(index);
        file.setStatus(percentage);
        data.set(0, file);
        setValueAt(percentage, index, 2);
        fireTableRowsUpdated(index, 2);

    }
}
```

**My File Model Component:**

```
public class FileDTO {

    private String fileName;
    private Long size;
    private Integer status =0;

    public FileDTO(File file) {

        this.fileName = file.getName();
        this.size = file.length();
    }

//setters & getters
```

**Handler to update the table from Upload:**

```
handler = new IProgressHandler() {

        @Override
        public void update(int index, int percentage) {
            uploadTableModel.updateProgress(index,percentage);

        }
    };
```

Please kindly suggest me to achieve this.

Comment: probably unrelated: your model isn't notifying on setValueAt - which is a must

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your IProgressHandler is executing on the EDT so the GUI can't repaint itself until the upload is finished.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html). You should probably be using a SwingWorker for this task.